# Replacing text in sed with escape characters

Tags: unix, sed

I have a very large file where I need to replace the characters `\x01\n` with the character `\n`. How would this be done with `sed`? So far I have:

```
$ sed -i 's/\x01\n/\n' file
```

> extra characters at the end of d command

But perhaps I'm missing a few escape characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't write `\n` in the line oriented `sed`:

```
sed -i 's/\x01$//' file
```

Comment: I suppose that would work, but it's possible that there is a `\x01` character without a line-break that we don't want to remove. It's a technicality I suppose and not sure if it exists in the actual file, but that's the main reason why.

Comment: The `$` stands for end-of-line, so this command only removes the `\x01` at the end-of-line. When you want to remove all '\x01', ypu can remove the `$` and add `g` for global or use `tr`.

Comment: oh, I see got it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are just missing the closing `'/'`:

```
$ sed -i 's/\x01\n/\n/' file
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -zi 's/\x01\n/\n/g' file
```

This slurps in the whole (or parts delimited by `\x00`) file and replaces `\x01\n` by `\n` globally.